# What is the terminology for the states of network connectivity?

Tags: single-word-requests, programming, internet

When describing the connectivity of a system to a network, are there unambiguous terms for if a member of the network should/can communicate over the network?

| Network Communicable | Can | Cannot |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Should be | Connected/Online | Disconnected/Offline |
| Should not be | ? | Unconnected/Offline |

I have tried combing through Google/Wiktionary as well as some collections of network terminology (e.g. [liveaction](https://www.liveaction.com/resources/glossary/glossary-of-network-terms/) and now [the Internet Security Glossary](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4949) as well) but the closest thing I've found was a discussion on a [word reference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/unconnected-disconnected.1834518/#:%7E:text=disconnected%20%3D%20two%20things%20were%20connected,Hope%20this%20helps.) forum.

Clarification on "should vs can": I realize "should" may imply some inherent security or authorization on the server's side.  The specific context in which this question arose was trying to report a client's state to the user over a socket network.  So "should" is defined by the user's intent and "can" is defined by the actual connectivity of the sockets.  For example, if the user pressed a "disconnect" button and was still receiving messages over the network they would be in the quadrant marked by a "?".

Comment: You seek technical information that isn’t covered here. See if https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4949 is the sort of thing you’re looking for.

Comment: You say “should/can” but don't say who decides. Do you need to distinguish between *authorized*, *active*, *paired*, *connected*?

Comment: It looks like you're asking for a term for where an item *can* communicate over the network but *should not* be able to. I suspect the term will actually depend on why that's happening. I also suspect that this is better asked on a specialist site: you want technical terms, not general words.

Comment: I will try investigating more specialist sites, it may be that there's no "on word" solution here.

Thank you for the Internet Security Glossary, unfortunately, I have not found what I was looking for there.

I have added a clarification that it is the user/client that defines "should" and not the server.

Comment: I don't think there's a word for this. In your example, I would say "still connected" or "didn't disconnect". Similarly, I don't think there's a word for the state where you press the "off" button for a device but it stays on.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs on a technical site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I do not believe there is a clear, unambiguous word for each for each quadrant you've identified, if a user were presented with "connected", "disconnected", "unconnected" and "**misconnected**" as their options, they may be able to figure out which applies to which scenario.

That said, if the purpose is to keep a client informed and avoid ambiguity, I suggest giving a descriptive, even if wordy, status report rather than going for a single (potentially ambiguous) word.

Comment: **Detached** also works in this context.